# Android logs 'GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC' 'GC_FOR_MALLOC'

Tags: android, logging

While running my apps, I have got this kind of logs:

> GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 2K, 38% free 8772K/14087K, external 17480K/17998K, paused 87ms
>   GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 0K, 38% free 8772K/14087K, external 17480K/17998K, paused 67ms
>   GC_CONCURRENT freed 2125K, 47% free 6214K/11719K, external 7142K/8400K, paused 3ms+5ms

Does anyone know what these logs mean? Thanks in advance!

1. What is the difference between 'GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC', 'GC_FOR_MALLOC' and 'GC_CONCURRENT'. Are there some other 'GC' events?
2. What does '38% free 8772K/14087K' mean? What is '8772K' and what is '14087K'?
3. What does 'external 17480K/17998K' mean? What is '17480K' and what is '17998K'?

Thanks!

Answer (score 44):

Another place where the Dalvik garbage collector messages are explained is in this video: [Google I/O 2011: Memory management for Android Apps](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk)

At about 14 minutes into the presentation, he breaks down the message format.  (BTW, that video has really good info on debugging memory leaks)

Roughly speaking, the format is `[Reason] [Amount Freed], [Heap Statistics], [External Memory Statistics], [Pause Time]`

### Reason

Viktor/Robert already explained `GC_CONCURRENT`, `GC_FOR_MALLOC`, `GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC`.

There is also:

- `GC_HPROF_DUMP_HEAP` - If you dump heap by clicking the "dump heap" button from DDMS or programatically
- `GC_EXPLICIT` - If you call System.gc()

### Amount Freed

E.g. `freed 2125K`

Self explanatory

### Heap Statistics

E.g. `47% free 6214K/11719K`

These numbers reflect conditions after the GC ran.  The "47% free" and 6214K reflect the current heap usage.  The 11719K represents the total heap size.  From what I can tell, the heap can grow/shrink, so you will not necessarily have an OutOfMemoryError if you hit this limit.

### External Memory Statistics

E.g `external 7142K/8400K`

Note: This might only exist in pre-Honeycomb versions of Android (pre 3.0).

Before Honeycomb, bitmaps are allocated external to your VM (e.g. Bitmap.createBitmap() allocates the bitmap externally and only allocates a few dozen bytes on your local heap).  Other examples of external allocations are for java.nio.ByteBuffers.

### Pause Time

If it's a concurrent GC event, there will be two times listed.  One is for a pause before the GC, one is for a pause when the GC is mostly done.
E.g. `paused 3ms+5ms`

For non-concurrent GC events, there is only one pause time and it's typically much bigger.
E.g. `paused 87ms`

Answer (score 14):

I was also looking for this information.

GC stands for garbage-collector, which collects unused objects during runtime of your app.

1. - **GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC**: Means that the VM is trying to reduce the amount of memory used collectable objects, to make room for non-collectable objects.
   - **GC_FOR_MALLOC**: Means that the GC was triggered because there wasn't enough memory left on the heap to perform an allocation. Might be triggered when new objects are being created.
   - **GC_CONCURRENT**: Triggered when the heap has reached a certain amount of objects to collect.
2. I am guessing that the 38% free means that 38% of the heap is unused. 8772K would be the size of the used memory on the heap and 14087K would be the size of the heap.
3. I don´t know, sorry.

Please note that all of this information is based on a post from [Robert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/429176/robert) on a similiar question posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4976566/what-do-gc-for-malloc-and-gc-explicit-mean-in-android-logcat) on stackoverflow. All credit (as long as this is correct) goes to Robert.