# the log of GC on Android

Tags: android, garbage-collection

i face a problem on understand the GC log.

Log: GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 82K, 48% free 2829K/5379K, external 1702K/2137K, paused 28ms

Anyone can explain the meaning of the log?

Thanks.

Comment: Means Dalvik is trying to collect collectable objects to make some space for non-collectable ones. Most likely you've memory leaks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4976566/what-do-gc-for-malloc-gc-explicit-and-other-gc-mean-in-android-logcat

Comment: @fardjad how to you know memory leak @@??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this Google IO I once watched I believe the presenter (Patrick Dubroy) states the different logs, and their association: [Google I/O: Memory Management for Android Apps](http://dubroy.com/blog/google-io-memory-management-for-android-apps/)

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think those log messages are documented.

If you're developing with Eclipse you are supposed to use DDMS perspective | Allocation Tracker to track your memory allocations.

Comment: In fact, i don't know how to check the memory usage on runtime. Do you have any idea to check memory used?

Comment: @King Wu One can watch 'Allocation Size' in DDMS|Allocation Tracker (probably, while doing things with the application). If it steadily increases all the time somewhere then it's a bad sign.