# Understanding Android GC Messages

Tags: java, android, garbage-collection

I have the following message on my catlog,

```
GC_CONCURRENT freed 456K, 19% free 2753K/3360K, paused 5ms+9ms, total 378ms
```

I am trying to make sense of the last value total. I've checked other GC related question on the site they either have two pauses associated with the concurrent GC or a single total pause for the non concurrent GC. Why do i have two? Did my app paused for 5+9 ms or 378 ms? What exactly is total?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What do GC\_FOR\_MALLOC, GC\_EXPLICIT, and other GC\_\* mean in Android Logcat?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4976566/what-do-gc-for-malloc-gc-explicit-and-other-gc-mean-in-android-logcat)

Answer (score 6):

`GC_CONCURRENT`: Triggered when the heap is growing. So it can reclaim memory in time so the heap doesn't need to be enlarged

`GC_CONCURRENT` freed 456K

This part tells you how much memory was freed by this GC sweep

`GC_CONCURRENT` freed 456K, 19% free 2753K/3360K

This part tells how much % of the heap is free, the size of the alive objects and the total size of the heap. So in the above example the 19% free, there is 2753Kmemory in use and the total heap size is 3360K.

The last part of the log tells you how long the GC took. on a `GC_CONCURRENT` collection you will see 2 times. one at the beginning of the collection, and one at the end.

For `n`on-concurrent GC events, there is only one pause time and it's typically much bigger. E.g. paused 378ms

**Source:**

https://sites.google.com/site/pyximanew/blog/androidunderstandingddmslogcatmemoryoutputmessages

Another place where things are explained clearly...

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk

Comment: I know all of that, Your source does not address the question. I have THREE time values not TWO I know what paused 5ms+9ms this part means but what exactly is total?

Answer (score 6):

Don't have a definitive answer, but from what I get, GC_CONCURRENT is a garbage collection that runs in a separate thread. This means that while it might take a total of X ms (378 in your case) to run, your actual running thread will not be blocked for that long. It will only be blocked a bit at the beginning and at the end of the concurrent garbage collection process (5+9=14ms in your example)

This type of garbage collection is auto-triggered by the JVM when it decides it's a good time to do that (usually when the heap has grown dangerously high). Other types of GC, like GC_EXPLICIT (if I'm not mistaking on the name) is triggered when you do a

System.gc();

in your code. For this type of garbage collection it will only report one time (like Y ms) and in this case your thread will actually be blocked for that amount of time until this type of GC process finishes.

Answer (score 2):

From looking at some systraces I took it seems the total (378ms) does not reflect how long the GC actually paused your application. It does reflect how long the garbage collection took. The paused time is what you should look at for that.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4976566/what-do-gc-for-malloc-gc-explicit-and-other-gc-mean-in-android-logcat) it explains the garbage collection messages etc.
If you need more information watch this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk) from google about memory management

Comment: As I have said on my question I have check the similar questions on the site. Question you linked still does not answer my question. Did the application paused for 378 ms or not? all the answers assume a single time value I have two. I also know about the video and watched it.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk.

Watch the video around 17 minutes. The guy explains the logcat message in detail.

```
GC_CONCURRENT freed 456K, 19% free 2753K/3360K, paused 5ms+9ms, total 378ms
GC_CONCURRENT : Jumps in because Heap is growing
19% free 2753K/3360K After this collection 19% of memory is free. Check the heap usage.paused 5ms+9ms Time taken to collect garbage. Total pause time is 378ms.
```

Comment: I know about the video, it explains "paused 5ms+9ms" part which I already know but not the total 378. No where in the docs that total  time is explained.

Comment: 378ms is the total pause time