# android google maps v2 lag when markers are being drawn/updated

Tags: google-maps-android-api-2

What is the proper way to manage Markers in Google Maps API v2? I'm trying to update the viewport with only markers that are visible within that region and I'm using `OnCameraChangeListener` to know when to update the viewport with the latest markers. However, it looks like the map is not scrollable/zoomable whenever it is drawing or updating the markers. I've noticed that when `setIcon()` is being used, the lag is even worse. In Google Maps v1, I never had this trouble when I used ItemizedOverlays. Here the gist of my code that is experiencing the lag in the scrolling/zooming:

```
private void updatePinsOnMap(MapDisplayData mapDisplayData) {
    BitmapDescriptor bitmapDescriptor = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(getPinWithBadgeCount(2));
    List<LatLng> latlngs = Lists.newArrayList();
    for (NearbyPlaceEdge place : mapDisplayData.getPlaces()) {
        latlngs.add(place.latlng);
    }
    for (NearbyPlaceCluster cluster : mapDisplayData.getClusters()) {
        latlngs.add(cluster.latlng);
    }
    int numMarkersToPlot = latlngs.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < numMarkersToPlot; i++) {
        if (i < mMarkers.size()) {
            // recycle
            mMarkers.get(i).setPosition(latlngs.get(i));
        } else {
            final Marker m = mGoogleMap.addMarker(
                new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(latlngs.get(i))
                    .icon(bitmapDescriptor)
            );
            mMarkers.add(m);
        }
    }
    for (int i = mMarkers.size() - 1; i >= numMarkersToPlot; i--) {
        mMarkers.remove(i).remove();
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

I created a sample app with the above code and things work according to plan (i.e. no lagginess). I spent some time thinking about this and I believe it has something to do with the memory that is required for Google Maps v2. From looking at logcat, every time I move the map--which triggers the map update--I get a lot of gc messages like this on my Nexus 4

```
05-27 14:28:23.701: D/dalvikvm(2849): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1198K, 23% free 26889K/34504K, paused 112ms, total 112ms
```

Is this a potential memory leak within the API? My existing app already takes up some memory, but I figure that GMaps will be able to appropriately manage its own memory based on what is available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are doing too many calls to the API.

Every call to setPosition, remove and addMarker is doing IPC. I'd suggest limiting that to number lower than 100 if possible.

From the code I see you are doing some kind of clustering, which is a good start.

I would also suggest not calling remove for markers that go outside of the screen (unless necessary, e.g. clusters change because zoom changes) and keeping identity of markers, so markers that stay on screen are not repositioned or otherwise modified.

I've no problems with 20000 markers when using [Android Maps Extensions](https://code.google.com/p/android-maps-extensions/) clustering engine, which does what I described.

**Update after question update:**

A different story now. Your app is using about 25 MB. This will be problematic for Maps API v2, because every call (like I said before) is doing IPC, which in turn forces GC according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4976731/2183804) and other sources. The bigger heap means the more time it will take to GC.

Solution? It would be preferable to keep your memory footprint much lower.

Comment: thanks for the insight Maciej. however, I'm not really adding/removing/updating a very large number of pins. It is around 25 markers at any given onCameraChangeListener callback. I'm updating my question with more information