# GC run too often

Tags: android, google-maps, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

This is a general question.
In my application the garbage collector is running too often (several times per second) and doesn't free a lot of memory (less than 1Mb).
The thing is, the heap size doesn't grow anymore. It takes about 40Mb, sometimes 60Mb on other phones where the maximum for an application is 128Mb (Galaxy S4) or 196Mb (Nexus 4).

Why does the GC run so often ?

Below is a part of the logcat when the GC runs too often. The application is freezing. I don't even do anything, I just try to zoom a map.

```
06-07 16:50:52.003: D/dalvikvm(26176): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 256K, 18% free 60015K/72980K, paused 51ms, total 51ms
06-07 16:50:52.053: D/dalvikvm(26176): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 256K, 18% free 60016K/72980K, paused 51ms, total 51ms
06-07 16:50:52.113: D/dalvikvm(26176): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 256K, 18% free 60016K/72980K, paused 52ms, total 52ms
06-07 16:50:52.163: D/dalvikvm(26176): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 256K, 18% free 60017K/72980K, paused 52ms, total 52ms
06-07 16:50:52.213: D/dalvikvm(26176): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 256K, 18% free 60017K/72980K, paused 51ms, total 52ms
06-07 16:50:52.273: D/dalvikvm(26176): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 256K, 18% free 60018K/72980K, paused 51ms, total 51ms
06-07 16:50:52.324: D/dalvikvm(26176): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 256K, 18% free 60018K/72980K, paused 51ms, total 51ms
06-07 16:50:52.374: D/dalvikvm(26176): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 256K, 18% free 60019K/72980K, paused 52ms, total 52ms
06-07 16:50:52.434: D/dalvikvm(26176): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 256K, 18% free 60019K/72980K, paused 53ms, total 53ms
06-07 16:50:52.484: D/dalvikvm(26176): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 256K, 18% free 60020K/72980K, paused 52ms, total 52ms
06-07 16:50:52.544: D/dalvikvm(26176): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 256K, 18% free 60020K/72980K, paused 56ms, total 56ms
06-07 16:50:52.594: D/dalvikvm(26176): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 256K, 18% free 60021K/72980K, paused 52ms, total 52ms
06-07 16:50:52.654: D/dalvikvm(26176): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 256K, 18% free 60021K/72980K, paused 52ms, total 52ms
06-07 16:50:52.704: D/dalvikvm(26176): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 256K, 18% free 60022K/72980K, paused 52ms, total 52ms
06-07 16:50:52.754: D/dalvikvm(26176): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 256K, 18% free 60022K/72980K, paused 52ms, total 52ms
06-07 16:50:52.814: D/dalvikvm(26176): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 256K, 18% free 60023K/72980K, paused 52ms, total 52ms
06-07 16:50:52.864: D/dalvikvm(26176): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 256K, 18% free 6023K/72980K, paused 51ms, total 51ms
06-07 16:50:52.924: D/dalvikvm(26176): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 256K, 18% free 60024K/72980K, paused 55ms, total 56ms
06-07 16:50:52.974: D/dalvikvm(26176): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 256K, 18% free 60024K/72980K, paused 52ms, total 52ms
06-07 16:50:53.024: D/dalvikvm(26176): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 256K, 18% free 60025K/72980K, paused 52ms, total 52ms
```

Comment: You should only care about the GC if your application is suffering from pauses or if you are running out of memory - which one of these apply to your app? (Also Android does try to minimize the pauses due to GC - may be it is freeing little at a time due to lack of demand. Whenever I've seen the GC messages in adb logcat - I always remember them being few hundreds of Kbs.)

Comment: Both. I display a google map (v2) and the GC running causes the map to be a bit too slow. I also rarely get OutOfMemory error for allocation of 2Mb.

Comment: Have you tried setting largeHeap=true http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#AndroidManifestApplication_largeHeap ?

Comment: Didn't change anything. I've edited my question to add what I see on the log cat. Don't know if that could give yo a hint. Thanks anyway to take your time.

Comment: Hmm. Sounds like your app continuosly allocates and frees 256K - almost like in a tight loop. Without looking at the code it is very hard to tell anything but you may want to lookup DDMS Allocation Tracker to track down what is allocating and freeing memory constantly - may be that code can be optimized.

Comment: Yeah, maybe. But why, because there is still 12Mb and it can take up to 120Mb, is GC called ? Shouldn't it take more memory and free several Mb in one go ?

Comment: It's not that simple - if demand is 256Kb and it can fulfill that by a single free - depending on various factors the GC may decide to not increase heap and instead satisfy the alloc request from current heap. If you want to see if it does stretch the heap size - try allocating 12Mb - in that case since it doesn't find that much that can be freed - it will increase the heap size.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is related to how Google Maps Android API works and how much memory is allocated by your application.

40-60 MB might problematic because it takes longer to execute single GCollection. As a side note: I noticed adding 1000 markers takes significantly longer when having 15 MB allocated comapred to when having 5 MB.

In addition to that every call to the Google Play Services APIs is doing IPC, which in turn forces GC according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4976566/what-do-gc-for-malloc-gc-explicit-and-other-gc-mean-in-android-logcat/4976731#4976731). It is possible that such IPC calls are done when panning or zooming.

It would be preferable to keep your memory footprint much lower.

Answer (score 0):

The GC runs when it needs to.  In general, (even on the DVM) it really does know, way better than you do, when it needs to run.  If you frame this problem not as a problem with the GC, but as a problem with your app's memory, it might help you find a solution.

The most likely reason for frequent GCs is that you are nearly out of memory.  This could happen, for instance, if you allocate lots of short-lived objects:  You allocate them fast, but forget them just as quickly.  Every time the GC runs, it successfully recovers enough memory for the app to continue... but just as quickly, you fill memory again.

If this is actually what is happening, then, if you had more memory, as suggested by @parry, you would just delay the problem.  GCs would occur less frequently, but take longer to run (because they would collect more garbage).  That might be sufficient, but probably not.

Check to see if you are allocating objects in a routine that is called frequently (for instance, your draw routines).

Comment: I'm with @parry.  Look for allocations in a tight loop.

Comment: You're assuming the GC is smart. If what you're saying would be true, the GC would differentiate between 1000 1 byte allocations and 1000 100 bytes allocations, apparently since the freed size is small, it seems it doesn't.

Answer (score -3):

If you believe the GC is acting stupid (quite possible), and that the VM has more memory to spare, then you could try forcing it to increase the heap size by asking for a one off 1/5/10 MB allocation (guarding it with a try-catch for OOME).
This might cause the GC to clean up more on each cycle, or increase the chances for a full GC to occur.
Another heuristic, which works on a PC, is calling System.GC() x times in a loop to trigger a full GC.
All in all, I came across it myself and it sucks.