# Is GC_FOR_ALLOC different from GC_FOR_MALLOC?

Tags: android, android-memory

https://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-memory.html refers to `GC_FOR_MALLOC`, which I do not see in my log. It does not refer to `GC_FOR_ALLOC` at all.

I do see `GC_FOR_ALLOC`:

```
03-12 10:11:02.382: D/dalvikvm(21382): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5383K, 30% free 27403K/39060K, paused 48ms, total 49ms
03-12 10:11:20.912: D/dalvikvm(21382): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 8100K, 30% free 27392K/39060K, paused 63ms, total 63ms
```

What is the difference between these two GC events?

Answer (score 1):

`GC_FOR_ALLOC` is just the new name that is used for `GC_FOR_MALLOC` on newer versions of Android, so they're the same. Google should really update that documentation :/

I got the answer from here in case you want to check it out: [What do GC_FOR_MALLOC, GC_EXPLICIT, and other GC_* mean in Android Logcat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4976566/what-do-gc-for-malloc-gc-explicit-and-other-gc-mean-in-android-logcat)