# android: LogCat does not tell me the available/free memory

Tags: android, memory-management, profiling

The guy in the Google IO video tells me to look at the log output from logcat to determine the available memory:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk (at 28:37)

this user also pasted the logcat lines including % of free memory:
[How to check memory leakage from message log in Logcat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8858249/how-to-check-memory-leakage-from-message-log-in-logcat)

Unfortunately MY logcat does NOT print the percentage of free memory:

```
D/dalvikvm(15670): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 594 objects / 10616 bytes in 23ms
```

Can someone tell me why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logcat messages are dependent on your device and possibly the OS version.

ex: For me, the Android 1.5 simulator showed no free memory %, but the Android 3.0 did show the free memory %.

Comment: can you tell me how to get trace log the available memory percentage?