# Are These For Memory Leak Warnings

Tags: android, memory-management, memory-leaks

In my log cat i see too much warnings like this;

> 05-11 23:21:44.225: D/dalvikvm(7578): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 11K, 47%
>   free 2881K/5379K, external 11655K/11801K, paused 39ms 05-11
>   23:21:44.300: D/dalvikvm(7578): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 2K, 47% free
>   2880K/5379K, external 10083K/10303K, paused 22ms 05-11 23:21:44.360:
>   D/dalvikvm(7578): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 1K, 47% free 2880K/5379K,
>   external 10083K/10303K, paused 22ms 05-11 23:21:44.415:
>   D/dalvikvm(7578): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed <1K, 47% free 2879K/5379K,
>   external 10083K/10303K, paused 23ms 05-11 23:21:44.480:
>   D/dalvikvm(7578): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed <1K, 47% free 2880K/5379K,
>   external 10009K/10262K, paused 23ms 05-11 23:21:44.555:
>   D/dalvikvm(7578): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 1K, 47% free 2879K/5379K,
>   external 10681K/10938K, paused 22ms

are these warning about memory leak or just warning?

I tested my app at two different device. One of them give these debug warning (Samsung Galaxy Note) other one is (Samsung Galaxy Mini) doesnt. Is this difference between two device normal?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4550757/844882

Answer (score 1):

Here is an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6933882/1376688) about Dalvik garbage collector messages.

> I tested my app at two different device. One of them give these debug warning 
>    (Samsung Galaxy Note) other one is (Samsung Galaxy Mini) doesnt.
>        Is this difference between two device normal?

I think it is normal because some handsets i work with gives theese logs too while some others dont

Answer (score 0):

"GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed" just means that the Garbage Collector has freed an external memory allocation. This has nothing to do with memory leaks :-)

Comment: I watched all logs via Eclipse. Any warning (GC_* warnings) include package name but for my app's GC warnings include my app's package name. Is this difference about debug mode and release mode?