# What exactly are the numbers in logcat's GC_CONCURRENT saying?

Tags: android, garbage-collection, logcat

example:

```
GC_CONCURRENT freed 1926K, 56% free 4739K/10660K, paused 2ms+3ms, total 39ms
```

My guesses:

1. freed = memory freed by the GC, easy enough.
2. free = current amount of the app's allocated heap that is free?
3. paused = this is where I don't know.. obviously it represents the pause caused by the GC stopping execution, but why two numbers, and what does each mean?
4. total? total of what? 2ms + 3ms != 39ms, so I'm not sure.

Comment: should check this http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk explained here the ms is the pause time. GC_CONCURRENT: Triggered when the heap is growing and this https://sites.google.com/site/pyximanew/blog/androidunderstandingddmslogcatmemoryoutputmessages

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550757/android-logs-gc-external-alloc-gc-for-malloc/6933882#6933882